# Proof of equivalent condition for $\sum_{x\in X}f(x)$ being absolutely convergent (Lemma 8.2.3 in Tao's Analysis 1)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, infinity

> **Lemma  8.2.3** Let $X$ be a countable set, and let $f:X \rightarrow\mathbb R$ be a function. Then the series $ \sum_{x \in X}  f(x)$ is absolutely convergent if and only if
>   $$
> \sup \left\{ \sum_{x \in A} |f(x)|: A \subseteq X, A\text{ finite}  \right\} < \infty 
> $$.

First, I have no idea how to prove it formally. As far as idea about the theorem is concerned, I can sense that if $\sum_{x \in X}  |f(x)| \leq  L$ since it is convergent (say to $L'$ which is $\leq L$). So, any summation over any finite set will be less than $\infty$. But, what about converse of the theorem and how to prove these result.

for converse part: 
As a counterexample, this result does not seem to hold for when $f(n)= \frac{1}{n}$ as Supremum of the above set seems to be finite for any finite set but $\sum_{x \in X} f(x)$ is divergent.

Comment: What is the book's definition of $\sum_{x \in X} f(x)$ for nonnegative $f$? (What I know is that $\sum_{x \in X} f(x) := \sup\{\sum_{x \in A} f(x), A \subset X$ finite$\}$, or, equivalently, $\sum_{x \in X} f(x) := \int_X f d \mu$ with $\mu$ the counting measure)

Comment: Expressions of the form $\sum_{x\in X} f(x)$ are not "series", since no  numbering $k\mapsto x_k$ has been specified. You would have to show us the definition of convergence of such expressions.

Comment: @AhmedHussein : According to book, there exist a bijection $g:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow X$ and $\sum_{x \in X}f(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f(g(n))$, Now use the defintion of convergence of series that $S_{M}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f(g(M)) $, and $\{ S_{M} \}_{M=0}^{\infty}$ to prove convergence of $\sum_{x \in X} f(x)$

Comment: @ChristianBlatter In the Above comment, we can  define it in the form of series and then prove the convergence of the series.

Comment: "Supremum of the above set for any finite set seems to be finite." Wrong. For $X=N$ and $f(n)=1/n$ ,the supremum is over the infinite collection of values  within the brace brackets. There are infinitely many finite  $A\subset N.$

Comment: @user254665: I agree with the fact there are infinite collection of values withing brace backets, (I think its uncountably infinite), but still with $A$ being finite, why can I not say that supremum is also finite? I am thinking in the line of. say any real line interval (0,1), though this has uncountably infinite number of points, any point is bounded by a real number. In fact any subset that can be formed from this set will be bounded. So, why can't I use the same argument for supremum? Can you disprove  "what you wrote" formally?

Comment: Example: Let $X=N$ and let $f(x)=x$ for all $x\in N$.   The general  problem is that although we are considering only finite $A\subset N$, there may be infinitely many such $A$ and infinitely many values in $S=\{\sum_{x\in A}|f(x)|\}.$  Choosing any function $f$ at random may result in $S$ being any countable subset of $R$, not necessarily a bounded subset.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g: \Bbb N \to X$ be a bijection. If $\sum_{x \in X} f(x)$ is absolutely convergent, then $\sum_{n \in \Bbb N} |f(g(n))|$ is convergent, hence:

$$\infty > \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |f(g(n))| = : L.$$

Given $A \subset X$ a finite set, we have:

$$\sum_{x \in A} |f(x)| = \sum_{n \in g^{-1}(A)} |f(g(n))| \le \sum_{n \in \Bbb N} |f(g(n))| = L$$

Hence

$$\sup\left\{ \sum_{x \in A} |f(x)|, A \subseteq X \text{ finite } \right\} \le L < \infty$$

**Edit**

Suppose that:

$$\sup\left\{ \sum_{x \in A} |f(x)|, A \subseteq X \text{ finite } \right\} =: L < \infty$$

Let $n \in \Bbb N$. Then, $g(\{1,\ldots, n\}) =:A$ is a finite subset of $X$. Hence,

$$\sum_{x \in A} |f(x)| \le L$$

But:

$$\sum_{x \in A} |f(x)| = \sum_{x\in g(\{1,\ldots, n\}) } |f(x)| = \sum_{k \in \{1,\ldots, n\}} |f(g(k))| = \sum_{k=1}^n |f(g(k))|.$$

Hence

$$\sum_{k=1}^n |f(g(k))| \le L.$$

and this is true for all $n \in \Bbb N$.

This shows that the series $\sum_{n \in \Bbb N} |f(g(n))|$ is convergent. Therefore, $\sum_{x \in X} f(x)$ is absolutely convergent.

Comment: @MUH what is a countably finite set?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I think I need a break from this,  I meant countably infinite. I don't think I can prove the other way round. does my contradictory example hold true? the counterexample, this result does not seem to hold for when $f(n)=1/n$ as Supremum of the above set seems to be finite for any finite set but $\sum_{x \in X} f(x)$  is divergent.

Comment: @MUH no worries. No, it doesn't because the statement is actually true. But to see why it doesn't work, I think you need to read the lemma once again to understand what that supremum actually is

Comment: See if this argument fits or not, Let's start with the $\sum_{x \in X}  f(x)$ being divergent, so $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |f(g(n))| = \sup_{n \in \Bbb N} \sum_{k=0}^n |f(g(k))| > p $ for any $p \in \mathbb{R}$  which means that there certainly exist $k_p$ s.t. $ \sup_{k_p \in \Bbb N} \sum_{k=0}^{k_p} |f(g(k))| > p $. This way, for all the finite $k_q$, the summation is greater than some real number $q$ and hence not finite.